# why there is space between image and border?

Tags: javascript, html, css

could you please tell me why there is space between image and border ?
here is my code
https://plnkr.co/edit/nBXb6vT2e39c5cZKUimM?p=preview

[image]

```
 <div class="first_news">
            <div class="top_new_header">
               <div class="info">
                   <p>Sports / IPL</p>
                   <p>TT of India | Apr 19, 2018 | 22:03:25 IST</p>
               </div>
                <div class="image_heading">
                    <div class="img_heading_div">
                        <img src="https://static.toiimg.com/photo/msid-63716346/63716346.jpg?pl=63716346"/>

                    </div>
                    <h1>Rajasthan Royals vs Delhi Daredevils, Match 6, Jaipur - RR beat DD by 10 runs (DLS)</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**space is right and bottom**

Comment: Also post your css

Comment: why wouldn't there be space?  the border is on a parent div with different width & height defined than child img element.

Comment: It’s due to the `border: 3px solid #fff;` rule in the `.image_heading .img_heading_div` selector. Use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525), inspect your elements and see what their styles and box models are.

Comment: how to reduce this space with border

Comment: `img {display: block}` or `img {display: inline-block; vertical-align: bottom` (or `top` or `middle`, just not the _default_ `baseline`)}

Answer (score 1):

Inline tags tend to fill the space as much as their height and width. You need to define your img as a block level item inside the parent div. The `img` tag is not a block-level element. In order to make it fill the gap, add this property to your css:

```
    .img_heading_div img {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of `border: 3px solid #fff;` on this part of your css :

```
.image_heading .img_heading_div{
        width: 40%;
        border: 3px solid #fff;
        margin: 0px 15px 0px -23px;
        display: inline-block;
    }
```

Comment: how to reduce this space with border

Comment: For a smaller border, you can change that line to `border: 1px solid #fff;`

Comment: Even setting the border-width to 1px won't solve your problem. Inline tags tend to fill the space as much as their height and width. You need to define your img as a block level item inside the parent div.

Answer (score 0):

Change your css

```
.img_heading_div img {
width: 130px;
height: 70px;
}
```

to this

```
.img_heading_div img {
width: 100%;
height: 70px;
}
```

by setting width to 100% you are telling the image to fill its parent width,so there would be no space,and iam not sure why there's space in the bottom